Athena how to debug/check query result?
I have problem with Athena query. Let say I have query like SELECT * FROM A LIMIT 100 - everything is ok, I have got response. But now, the same query without limit worked for 30min and return error, so I have changed Athena soft limit to 180min. Now query takes ~1h30min but return nothing (0 errors or correct rows). I would like to somehow investigate this and few other problems. Can I somehow collect logs for Athena query (what is done under the neath)? I have found only how to enable metrics, but it is not enough. How can I debug this kind of situations?

Another option is to figure out how to optimise the query so it returns faster. How many files is it querying, what is their size and what is their format? Queries will run faster if the data is stored in snappy-compressed parquet files, especially if there are WHERE or JOIN clauses being used.
